# Why wordpress showe "admin is editing..." whoever edits?

Tags: users, warnings, support

Wordpress warns users when two of them are editing the same article, but the warning always says "admin is editing this page". Admin is currently logged off and the message is caused by another author.

Language files have the %s in place.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate post meta values related to this behavior:

- `_edit_lock` - holds timestamp when post was last locked;
- `_edit_last` - hold ID of user who last edited post.

Most likely these somehow got out of sync - lock was triggered recently, but user wasn't properly updated. Hard to guess why from information you provided.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: @naugtur - I think Rast just wanted to say that this just can happen (is a glitch) and most likely it's not worth to trace as it is a temporary issue only. But if you think it's worth to trace, that would likely mean to make it reproduceable, and then debug it on a test-system. Probably too specific then. Is this causing really headaches? Or probably solved after stepping away for some minutes from the screen?

Comment: Yep, exactly (was going away from computer and didn't finish the thought properly). There are many ways this can happen once (I think failed database write is likely reason) and it's not worth worrying. But if this happens consistently - it will take plenty of code and testing (since we are talking about different users at the same time) to figure out.

Comment: I'll spend some more time on this on friday. I'm not sure yet, but it seems to happen everytime. I hacked it with replacing %s with "someone" in language files. My wordpress install will be used by at most 40 people with managed access, so this feature might be useful. I would totally ignore it if I were to use it for blogging with a friend.

Comment: Please give this an addtional update or in case rarsts answer helped you solving the issue, mark it as answer.